# Medical Machine Learning Data Set

Tags: data-mining

I'm researching Medical Data set which includes variable concerning illnesses and treatment type.

For example  illnesses  is colon cancer, it's decision variables (x,y,z,t)  and  treatment type is  chemothreapy, radiothreaphy etc etc.

I  want to reach  such a data set for my KDD  and exploratory lesson. Because I want to make  useful project prototype.

if you know any data set web site  pls  share me (so-called site may not include medical)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [standard machine learning data set repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html?format=&task=&att=&area=life&numAtt=&numIns=&type=&sort=dateDown&view=table) at UC Irvine. [**R**](http://www.r-project.org) users can access it via the [**mlbench**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=mlbench) package from the [**CRAN**](http://cran.r-project.org) network.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [UCI Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/). 189 sample ML datasets, many medical in nature.

Because the site is focussed on ML, it gives a lot of guidance that will help choose and tune your ML algorithms for good generalization performance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is an actual 'programming' question, strictly speaking. However, given that programs work on data, I'll go with it - and observe that the term 'medical dataset' returns quite a few (1.7m) hits in Google.

Comment: upvoting your magnanimity